# Pytorch - Project each row of a tensor to the column space of another tensor

Tags: pytorch

Currently, I have a tensor *A*, and a tensor *U* where *U* is an orthogonal matrix and is of full rank(so that its columns is a set of basis of *U*'s column space, and all columns, say, *u_i*, have a norm of 1).

I am trying to compute the projection of each row of *A* onto the column space of *U*, using the formula from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112728/how-do-i-exactly-project-a-vector-onto-a-subspace).

Which is, to compute Proj(A). [image]
Is there any convenient functions or better operations to achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a unit norm in each column of projection matrix, just simply

```
torch.mm(A,U)
```

should be sufficient.